# ng-quill wysiwyg editor not showing full toolbar

Tags: angularjs, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

am working on project with asp mvc and angularjs which needs a wysiwyg editor so i sellect ng-quill because it free and it has image upload feature which i specifically need. but the problem is when i put it in to my site the full  toolbar did't show up. i have followed exactly like the demo shows [ng-quill demo](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill/blob/develop/demo.html)

please help me!

```js
var ICTOnlineDatabaseApp = angular.module('ICTOnlineDatabaseApp',
    ['ngQuill']);
ICTOnlineDatabaseApp.config(['ngQuillConfigProvider', function (ngQuillConfigProvider) {
    ngQuillConfigProvider.set();
}]);
ICTOnlineDatabaseApp.controller('NewNewsController', [
                '$scope',
                '$timeout',
                function ($scope, $timeout) {
                    $scope.title = 'Quill works';
                    $scope.readOnly = false;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.title += ' awsome!!!'
                    }, 2000);
                    $scope.editorCreated = function (editor) {
                        console.log(editor);
                    };
                    $scope.contentChanged = function (editor, html, text) {
                        console.log('editor: ', editor, 'html: ', html, 'text:', text);
                        console.log('Had had hadmeles');
                    };
                }
]);
```

```css
[ng-quill-editor] { display: block; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.snow.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.bubble.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-quill/2.2.1/ng-quill.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ICTOnlineDatabaseApp">
  <div ng-controller="NewNewsController">
    <ng-quill-editor ng-model="message" toolbar="true" link-tooltip="true" image-tooltip="true" toolbar-entries="font size bold list bullet italic underline strike align color background link image" editor-required="true" required="" error-class="input-error"></ng-quill-editor>
</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: oh God it worked hear !!!!

Comment: sorry guy's the problem is the include library that i use i changed all to cdn and now it worked.